# Perl map using object method

Tags: perl, map-function, instance-method

I have a Perl Module file `MyClass.pm` with a very basic class definition.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyClass;

sub new {
    my $this = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $this;
    return $self;
}

sub displayChar{
    my $self = shift;
    my $char = shift;
    print $char . "\n";
}

1;
```

Also I have a `myClass.pl` file that creates an instance of MyClass.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyClass; 
my $myClass = MyClass->new();

$myClass->displayChar('a'); # This line works right

my @charArray = ('a', 'b', 'c');
map($myClass->displayChar, @charArray);
```

When I call the `displayChar` method it works right, but when I try to use map function with that method it gives me this error three times (once per array item, I guess):

```
Use of uninitialized value $char in concatenation (.) or string at MyClass.pm line 16.
```

Am I using map function in a wrong way? Or maybe it's not possible to use an object method as first param?

Comment: Please don't use `new MyClass`. This is not Java. `new` is not a keyword. `MyClass->new()` will save you much potential confusion in the future.

Comment: Ok! I edited the question to better illustrate the example. Thanks for the tip @DaveCross

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a value to your `displayChar` method:

```
map($myClass->displayChar($_), @charArray);
```

[map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) locally sets the $_ variable to each value of your array.

Comment: @nanocv: I find the block version of `map` makes things clearer - `map { $myClass->displayChar($_) } @charArray;`. Also, if you're not doing something with the list returned by `map`, you should be using `foreach` instead` - `$myClass->displayChar($_) foreach @charArray;`